# hadoop api configuration on the client machine

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

*ultra-noob*. I have a server machine with cdh3u1 pseudo-distrib, and a client machine with a java application using the cdh3u1 API.

How do I configure the client to talk to the server? I've been googling for hours and couldn't find where is the "client configuration" file. The "hdfs-default", "core-default" and "mapred-default" and their "-site" counterparts all look like server (namenode and datanode) config to me.

Is it just "multipurpose client server" config and I should cherry-pick the attributes in these files that are appropriate to the client? which are they? probably missing something big here...

Thanks, Ido

Answer (score 5, accepted):

make sure that the client machine can access the hadoop server machine ip. If you use a virtualbox for the hadoop server (cdh3 vm), then add a "host-only" network interface (see details here: [host-only networking with virtualbox](http://christophermaier.name/2010/09/01/host-only-networking-with-virtualbox.html). I'm assuming that your static ip for the hadoop server is `192.168.56.101` and that you're able to ping it from your client.

configure a hostname for your hadoop server machine in both the server and client machine. If you want to name your hadoop server "local-elephant", add the following line to /etc/hosts in both machines: `192.168.56.101 local-elephant`.

in the server machine goto /etc/hadoop/conf change the values of the following properties from "localhost" to "local-elephant": in core-site.xml the value of `fs.default.name` and in mapred-site.xml the value of `mapred.job.tracker`.

in the client machine, create core-site.xml and mapred-site.xml in the classpath of your java application. In those files put only the `fs.default.name` and `mapred.job.tracker` properties.